# Changing decimal to mm:ss format Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have duration in decimal format in excel, e.g. 35.78 minutes, which I wanted to change to minute/second format so e.g. 35.78minutes becomes 35 minutes 47seconds in excel. Any way I can format it that way? I have tried the custom filter of mm:ss but that does not work

Comment: Divide **35.78** by **1440** and set format as `mm:ss` or `mm "minutes" ss "seconds";`

Comment: Thank you! What is the logic behind it?

Comment: This is simple maths, 24 represents the total hours in day and 60 means numbers of minutes in an hour. on dividing by both gives you the output to convert a time in decimal to excel time.

Comment: You can refer this link to know more and learn as well, **[Convert_Time_In_Decimal_To_Excel_Time](https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-decimal-hours-to-excel-time)**

Answer (score 3):

You need some math operation to convert decimal values to time values. Try-

```
=(A1/24)/60
```

Then format the cell as `mm:ss`

Or direct formula `=TEXT((A1/24)/60,"mm:ss")`

[image]